# Pandas rolling mean not working

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I am trying to calculate rolling mean on df below. But for some reason, it won't calculate. I have used the same code snippet else where in my code and there it seems to be working fine.

I am using Python 2.7 and Pandas 0.20.2

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print 'df head \n', df.head(50)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'rolling_mean':df.groupby(['PersonID','Date'])['count_of_metric'].rolling(15,1).mean()})
print 'df1 head \n',df1.head(50)
```

Here is what I am getting. Can anyone help?

```
df head 
         PersonID        Date  count_of_metric  TO_DROP
354    0-Orphan22  2012-11-08              0.0        0
531    0-Orphan22  2012-11-09              2.0        0
177    0-Orphan22  2012-11-10              0.0        0
355    0-Orphan22  2012-11-11              0.0        0
532    0-Orphan22  2012-11-12              0.0        0
0      0-Orphan22  2012-11-13              1.0        0
356    0-Orphan22  2012-11-14              0.0        0
533    0-Orphan22  2012-11-15              0.0        0
1      0-Orphan22  2012-11-16              0.0        0
178    0-Orphan22  2012-11-17              0.0        0
534    0-Orphan22  2012-11-18              0.0        0
2      0-Orphan22  2012-11-19              0.0        0
179    0-Orphan22  2012-11-20              2.0        0
357    0-Orphan22  2012-11-21              0.0        0
3      0-Orphan22  2012-11-22              0.0        0
180    0-Orphan22  2012-11-23              0.0        0
358    0-Orphan22  2012-11-24              0.0        0
535    0-Orphan22  2012-11-25              0.0        0
181    0-Orphan22  2012-11-26              0.0        0
359    0-Orphan22  2012-11-27              0.0        0
536    0-Orphan22  2012-11-28              0.0        0
4      0-Orphan22  2012-11-29              0.0        0
360    0-Orphan22  2012-11-30              0.0        0
537    0-Orphan22  2012-12-01              0.0        0
182    0-Orphan22  2012-12-03              0.0        0
361    0-Orphan22  2012-12-04              0.0        0
5      0-Orphan22  2012-12-05              0.0        0
183    0-Orphan22  2012-12-06              0.0        0
362    0-Orphan22  2012-12-07              0.0        0
538    0-Orphan22  2012-12-08              0.0        0
363    0-Orphan22  2012-12-10              0.0        0
539    0-Orphan22  2012-12-11              0.0        0
6      0-Orphan22  2012-12-12              0.0        0
576         10-22  2012-11-12              0.0        0
50          10-22  2012-11-13              0.0        0


df1 head 
                             rolling_mean
PersonID     Date                        
0-Orphan22   2012-11-08 354           0.0
             2012-11-09 531           2.0
             2012-11-10 177           0.0
             2012-11-11 355           0.0
             2012-11-12 532           0.0
             2012-11-13 0             1.0
             2012-11-14 356           0.0
             2012-11-15 533           0.0
             2012-11-16 1             0.0
             2012-11-17 178           0.0
             2012-11-18 534           0.0
             2012-11-19 2             0.0
             2012-11-20 179           2.0
             2012-11-21 357           0.0
             2012-11-22 3             0.0
             2012-11-23 180           0.0
             2012-11-24 358           0.0
             2012-11-25 535           0.0
             2012-11-26 181           0.0
             2012-11-27 359           0.0
             2012-11-28 536           0.0
             2012-11-29 4             0.0
             2012-11-30 360           0.0
             2012-12-01 537           0.0
             2012-12-03 182           0.0
             2012-12-04 361           0.0
             2012-12-05 5             0.0
             2012-12-06 183           0.0
             2012-12-07 362           0.0
             2012-12-08 538           0.0
             2012-12-10 363           0.0
             2012-12-11 539           0.0
             2012-12-12 6             0.0
10-22        2012-11-12 576           0.0
             2012-11-13 50            0.0
```

I am just typing here because it won't allow me to post this unless I add more details. It finds there is more code then details. please ignore this line.

Comment: What result are you expecting? Why are you grouping by person and date?

Comment: You give me a hint, stupid me. I should have grouped only by PersonID.